# When can I cast Adept spells? Where can I buy them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After completing the Eye of Magnus quest, Faralda was selling me adept spells.
By mistake I reloaded one old save and Faralda now doesn't sell me Adept Destruction spells anymore.
I tried reload many times and didn't work.

I'm level 12. What should I do?

Comment: This will either be fixed in a patch or won't happen frequently.

Comment: Had a similar experience. Walked into a shop. Accidentally sold stuff I wanted to keep. Reload the autosave. Boom - shopkeeper has no money. I had to quit the game and reload (ps3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, clear your system cache and it will be there.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm on PS3...

Comment: Just needed to restart it and was working.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 50 in the magic school you want to buy adept spell if I remember correctly.

Comment: I do have 54 in destruction... Shall we call it a bug?

Comment: Is the Eye of Magnus quest still active? Some options are blocked during this quest, you cannot talk to all the characters correctly.

Comment: The quest should be done (I can ask her what she sells etc etc), but it looks like that every time I walk through a door it auto saves. Should I reload an ancient saved game and redo some quests and try re-getting it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I couldn't find out what was wrong. Try the court mage in Whiterun Dragonsreach. I believe his inventory is based on what your level of destruction is.